# How to deploy JAR files to existing webapp subdirectory?

Tags: java, maven, jar

Let's say I have a very ordinary web app deployed via `mywebapp.war`, generated by `Maven`:

```
webapps
  |
  |--mywebapp.war
  |--mywebapp
       |
       |--images
       |--js
       |--jsp
       |--jardeploy
       |--META-INF
       |--styles
       |--WEB-INF
```

Now I would like to deploy `myjarfile1.jar` and `myjarfile2.jar` (or more) in `webapps/mywebapp/jardeploy`. They are artifacts of another Maven project, not the one that makes the war. They are also not jars that mywebapp uses, which would be under `WEB-INF/lib`, but rather downloadable jars built separately and not part of the mywebapp source code.

Is there a way to package an archive bundling the two or more jars in Maven which, when dropped in `webapps` will get deployed not in default `webapps/jardeploy` but in `webapps/mywebapp/jardeploy`? It would be the same as though I took the jars and copied them in that directory but I would like to follow the standard app server deployment protocol by dropping a generated artifact in webapps rather than the hacky former approach. I actually want a formal artifact (just like the war) instead of a post deploy add-on. Is there a way to tell (perhaps in the manifest) that it needs to unpack the jar and put it in that directory, if that directory exist?

The container shouldn't matter but it is Tomcat 7.

Comment: Why do you need to package them if they are not going to be used by your `mywebapp`? If you do use them in your `mywebapp`, then why do you need to deploy them to a different directory?

Comment: They are indeed used as a webstart launched from mywebapp. But their build process is entirely different from the containing web application. It's an app within an app.

Comment: It is similar to for example if the jars were a permanent download link on your site but, due to versioning, they need to be rebuilt often (and not be static files within the project structure). So you build your web app and then build the downloadable artifacts (which is what a webstart essentially is + runnable)

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to download these 2 maven dependencies to a different folder than the rest?

Comment: I don't want to download them. The user does that. I need to deploy them to a directory where they will be available for download, unlike `WEB-INF/lib`. But they need to be deployed AFTER the container application is deployed. Think of it as an amendment to an existing deployed app.

Comment: Can you post your current pom.xml file?

Comment: there are two, one for the container app and the other one to build the jars. but they are not really relevant as I explained the challenge in English and looking for a non-relativistic solution. IOW, there is nothing in those poms that should affect the solution I am seeking and posting them would be merely clutter obfuscation

Answer (score 5):

This looks like a standard use-case for maven-war-plugin and extra resources, unless I'm missing something.
For example [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html%20here) (See section Configuring web resources) tells you that you can include additional resources in your war build (and this is what your two jars are to me : additional resources)

If this doesn't work for you then maven-assembly-plugin allows you to specify a much more flexible format.

Comment: I was thinking of WAR but, when I tried it, it required a specific directory structure containing web.xml, which I don't have.

Comment: If you don't have web.xml then you're already outside "standard". Therefore, I think assembly plugin will allow you the most flexibility here.

Comment: Can't you put a dummy web.xml in there? Just to satisfy war plugin? I think you can exclude the web.xml file itself from packaging.

Comment: OK -- I will try it out and get back. Thanks

Comment: Sure. Also, maven-resources-plugin can also easily copy files; but if your setup gets more complex, it's just easier with assembly plugin.

Comment: The Maven war plugin has an option, failOnMissingWebXml, if you don't want to include a dummy web.xml. In addition the default value is false starting with 3.0.0, so if you use the latest version you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a webapp with a WebListener that copies the jar files to *mywebapp/jardeploy* directory. So when this application is deployed in your container it will copy the jars to the place you want.

I tested and it works! Supposing you have created this new webapp and have put the jars in *src/main/webapps/jars* directory, the WebListener look likes this:

```
@WebListener
public class Deployer implements ServletContextListener {

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        String realPath = sce.getServletContext().getRealPath("/jars");
        try {
            Files.copy(new File(realPath + "/myjarfile1.jar").toPath(), 
                new File(System.getProperty("catalina.base")+"/webapps/mywebapp/jardeploy/myjarfile1.jar").toPath());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        System.out.println("On shutdown web app");
    }
}
```

This code is just a proof of concept and can be enhanced, but it servers to its purpose. It only copies one jar (myjarfile1.jar) to */webapps/mywebapp/jardeploy*. 
PS: I created this new webapp using maven archetypes.